# DNN 7 in-place upgrade install folder contents

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am having some trouble upgrading my dnn 7 website.    I am upgrading from 7.0.5 to 7.0.6 and I have previously tried upgrading to 7.1.0 but I ran into errors, now I have left over files from the previous upgrades left in the instal/authSystem install/provider install/module folders.

Can I empty these folders before copying over the upgrade package over the current version?  Should they be empty? or how can I figure out what the default contents should be for the install folder when upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your question, simply empty the INSTALL folder and get the INSTALL folder from the upgrade package.

Really though, you should take your backup from before you attempted the upgrade, and take all of the files from that backup, and start with those, essentially starting with a clean folder, copy the files into that folder from the backup, then perform the upgrade.

Comment: thanks chris, should the install folder be empty after the upgrade is sucessful?  Or should I remove the previous version zip files?  I have been upgrading DNN for over two years without errors and now I have been fighting with a simple upgrade for days.  Just trying to understand where I might have gone wrong.  Also, do you know if I can go straight from 7.0.5 to 7.1.1?

Comment: It won't be empty after an upgrade, but to keep things clean you can definitely empty that out. Yes, you can go from 705 to 711