# DNN Source Code (Needed?) and Deployment (How?)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

1. Do we need the source code if we will primarily create (advanced) modules and occasionally modify the theme?
2. How does DNN get deployed from Teamcity / Octopus Deploy?

Comment: No, you don't need the source code to create modules. Or occasionally modify the theme.

Comment: How would you upgrade when DNN releases a newer version?

Comment: Found out how to perform in in-place upgrade:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470701/dnn-7-in-place-upgrade-install-folder-contents/18473052#18473052

Answer (score 2):

Your modules, and "skins" should be individual projects, and you should deploy those to production using Packaged ZIP files. That's the proper way to develop/deploy extensions for DNN

Comment: If View.ascx is in Proj1.csproj, how do you include View.ascx in the Website Project >DesktopModules folder and test locally?

Comment: Secondly, do you have any insight as to deployment using Octopus?

Comment: I answered a number of your other questions on the other thread, also about deployment.

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes, you should go to this url http://www.christoc.com/ to learn how to use a template to create a dnn module and create a skin as well.
Thanks to @ChrisHammond for your contribution to dnn community.